# I want my Arduino code to only take inputs from a button for 1 second

Tags: c++, arduino, robotics

I want my code to take inputs from my button for only 1 second but it doesn't stop at the 1-second mark. I am just starting to learn Arduino and I'm using a NODEMCU-32. This is my first time using c and c++ and this is the first time posting here so any feedback helps!

Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int lpin = 26; // LED pin
int bpin = 13; // button pin
int bcount = 0; // button counter
int milamount = 5; // increments to add to button counter

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   pinMode(lpin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(bpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   int bstate = digitalRead(bpin);

   // Once the button is pressed the code starts adding the increments to the button 
   counter
   if (bstate == HIGH) {

      bcount = bcount + milamount;
      digitalWrite(lpin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(bcount);
   }

   // Once the counter reaches 1000 the code stops receiving input from the button and 
   turns off the LED
   
   else if (bcount == 1000) {

      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
      // This resets the button counter after reaching 1000
      bcount = bcount - 1000;
   }

    else {
      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
    }

}
```

The counter keeps going up and never resets after reaching the 1000 mark. I am also new to c++ and c so any feedback is helpful, thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the comments and answers, the problem is resolved!

Comment: Consider your logic. You keep adding 5 to `bcount` while the button state is high. Only when it goes low to you take a punt that the value reached was precisely 1000. Maybe remove the `else` and make it `if (bcount >= 1000)` which is a bit more stable (works if you change `milamount` to 3 or anything that doesn't divide evenly into 1000). Then it's up to you whether you really want to subtract 1000, or simply do `bcount = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this doesn't work, I only compiled it. However I have modified your code so it seems like it should work, of course the comment on your question is fully correct I just thought I would come in and show you how I would do it. Hope this helps!

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int lpin = 26; // LED pin
int bpin = 13; // button pin
int bcount = 0; // button counter
int milamount = 5; // increments to add to button counter

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:

   pinMode(lpin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(bpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   int bstate = digitalRead(bpin);

   // Once the button is pressed the code starts adding the increments to the button counter

   if (bstate == HIGH && bcount < 1000) { // only if the bcount is smaller than 1000.
      bcount = bcount + milamount;
      digitalWrite(lpin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(bcount);
   } else if (bstate == LOW) { // if bstate is LOW the LED shouldn't turn on and the bcount should reset
      bcount = 0;
   }

   // Once the counter reaches 1000 the code stops receiving input from the button and turns off the LED

   if (bcount >= 1000) { //only if bcount is equal to or higher than 1000
      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
      // This resets the button counter after reaching 1000
      bcount = 0;
   } else {
      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

riffing off the above answer, it works however if you are concerned with acurracy you will want to use the processor clock to log the time.

you can use `millis()` to get the time since the processor started running

you can read more about the function here:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/

This would look something like:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int lpin = 26; // LED pin
int bpin = 13; // button pin
unsigned long bcount = 0; // button counter
unsigned longt bstart = 0; // holds the time at which the button is pressed
void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:

   pinMode(lpin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(bpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   int bstate = digitalRead(bpin);

   // Once the button is pressed we log the time then continue to update the time untill 1 second has passed

   if (bstate == HIGH && bcount < 1000) { // only if the bcount is smaller than 1000.
      // the button has just been pressed
      if(bstart == 0) {
         bstart = millis(); // grabbing the system clock
      } 
      bcount = millis() - bstart; // getting an accurate time elapsed reading
      digitalWrite(lpin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(bcount);
   } else if (bstate == LOW) { // if bstate is LOW the LED shouldn't turn on and the bcount should reset
      bcount = 0;
      bstart = 0;
   }

   // Once the counter reaches 1000 the code stops receiving input from the button and turns off the LED

   if (bcount >= 1000) { //only if bcount is equal to or higher than 1000
      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
      // This resets the button counter after reaching 1000
      bcount = 0;
      bstart = 0;
   } else {
      digitalWrite(lpin, LOW);
   }
}
```